# R plot first row of tibble as a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the Education.csv dataset from https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/county-level-data-sets/download-data/ and I have cleaned up the data removing columns 1-5. I would like to plot the first observation to show the trends of adults rates of education over the 5 decades of data I have. I know about the ggplot function, but I am not quite sure how to implement in this instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this,

```
USA <- eduLevelsbyCounty %>%
  filter(eduLevelsbyCounty$state == "US") %>%
  select(eduLevelsbyCounty, 2, 3, 8:43)

ggplot(USA, aes(x=USA$state))
```

but it did not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These government spreadsheets are a nightmare to work with.  It takes more effort than expected to get them into the correct format.
The comments in the script outlines the step by step procedure.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
eduLevelsbyCounty<-read_excel("/Users/Downloads/education.xls", skip=4)
USA <- eduLevelsbyCounty %>%
  filter(State == "US") %>% select(c(2, 3, 8:43))

library(tidyr)
#convert to a long dataframe 
df<-USA %>% pivot_longer(cols=c(3:ncol(USA)) )

#separate year from title in the first column
#(would recommend fixing the last 4 rows)
df<-df %>% separate(name, into=c("name", "year"), sep=", ")


library(ggplot2)
#make line graph
g<-ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=name, color=name)) + 
  geom_line()

print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: could I ask what the y value is being measured in?

Comment: @JayWehrman, The y value is from the first line of the spreadsheet, so you would have to review the source of the data.  Yes, the y axis could be confusing since it is displayed in scientific notation and not in a standard format.  This can changed by adding `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1))` to the ggplot statement.

Comment: ok thank you. I'm getting an error, Error: Result must have length 3662, not 0, when I try to run the first line. I think it may have something do with how i loaded in and cleaned the data up. Could I re-edit my post for clarification?

Comment: If you download the Excel file direct from the webpage then `readxl::read_excel()` function can read the file directly, as shown in my script, it should work correctly.